How do I import cdn script to html
I created a sample cdn script for and want to import to an html file but keep getting import error
In the html file,
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>MediaPLayer</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">test</div>



  <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/BigYusuf/widgetTest@master/Tawk.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

And for the app.js file

Is there something am missing

import { Tawk } from 'Tawk';

const player = new Tawk({
    position: 'bottom-right',
})



Here is the precise error
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "Tawk". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

This question is similar to: Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.  The library may be different, but the base advice is the same.
